# Need " " when concatenating strings?

Tags: java, string-concatenation

In the code below (return statement on the last line), do you need the " " between variable firstName and middleInitial? As long as one variable is a string, doesn't it concatenate everything else into a string also when linked together with + ?

So for example, does this also work?
return firstName + middleInitial + lastName
If not, why not?

```
 // A Name object represents a name such as "John Q. Public".
 public class Name {
     String firstName;
     char middleInitial;
     String lastName;

     // The name in normal order such as "John Q. Public".
     public String getNormalOrder() {
         return firstName + " " + middleInitial + ". " + lastName;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried each permutation?

Comment: @Bluejay Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The " " is necessary if you want a space between firstName and middleInitial. If you don't want a space, you can omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Middleinitial is not a String its a char. those strings are often used to add spaces between the strings

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

```
So for example, does this also work?
return firstName + middleInitial + lastName
If not, why not?
```

The answer is yes, it does work.  The result you end up with is `JohnQPublic`.

This code sample

```
return firstName + " " + middleInitial + ". " + lastName;
```

Returns `John Q. Public`.  The " " puts a space between firstName & middleInitial.  The ". " puts a period and a space between middleInitial and lastName

Another example of formatting the result would be

```
return String.format("%s %s. %s", firstName, middleInitial, lastName);
```

and you would get `John Q. Public`